# Flash Button stays down

Tags: flash

I'm building in flash a house. Now I want when I click on a door it stays open. 
I'm using an button for the effect.

I think I need some code to keep te button in the down state after I clicked it

Here's my Actionscript 3

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// SOUNDS
var sound_aaah:Sound = new Sound();
sound_aaah.load(new URLRequest("aaah.mp3"));
// END SOUNDS

// CLICK EVENTS

trapDeur.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trapDeurClick);

function trapDeurClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    sound_aaah.play();
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
// END CLICK EVENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Button object for your door, use a MovieClip. Draw the open door on a frame within that MovieClip and set the label "open" on that frame. Then in the Click function switch its frame by doing e.target.gotoAndStop("open");